# Is there any way to integrate Box.com files with SQL tables via SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integration, box

I need to automate the process of uploading SQL table data to folders in box.com. This is to avoid the manual process of converting sql tables to Excel or cvs file and uploading them to box.com. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Use OLEDB source as a source to connect to SQL server database and select the table  you want to load. Connect it to flat file destination type as a destination and use box sync folder on your computer as destination connection and create an agent job to automate it.